# laravel get real path of input file

Tags: php, laravel

i have script like this in my view

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ URL::route('import.produk.post') }}">
   <input type="file" name="import">
   <button class="btn btn-primary form-button" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

in my controller i wanna show path of file 
lets say that file located in `D:\Data\product.xlsx` 
i using this script to do that

```
public function postImportProduk() {
   $input = Input::file('import')->getRealPath();;
    var_dump($input);
}
```

but it's not display real path of the input file instead temp file like this output

```
string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD745.tmp"
```

i try with `->getFilename()` it's show temp filename too `phpD745.tmp`

but if i'm using `->getClientOriginalName()`it's show exactly `product.xlsx`

i wonder how to get file real path
ps : i'm using laravel 4.2

Comment: Because that's where the file is on upload. You need to move() it before you could have it in your storage

Comment: @DamienPirsy not quite understand...so i need move it first then run script `getRealPath` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do the upload, the file is stored in a temporary directory, with a randomly generated name.

Now that you have the file in your server, you want to move it to some specific folder that you have to designate. A simple example in your case would be this:

```
public function postImportProduk() {
    $input = Input::file('import');
    $destinationPath = '/uploads/'; // path to save to, has to exist and be writeable
    $filename = $input->getClientOriginalName(); // original name that it was uploaded with
    $input->move($destinationPath,$fileName); // moving the file to specified dir with the original name
}
```

Read more on the functionality [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files).

Comment: so it's not possible to know where original path of file...i want to save both original path and destination path to database....

Comment: What do you mean "original path"? If you want to know where the user is storing the file in his computer then no, it is not possible and would be a security issue if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the original file path is not possible for security purposes.

See More 
[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)