# Retrieving the absolute path of a file saved with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have this simple question:

how is possible to retrieve the absolute path of file just saved with laravel?

for example:

I saved the file with:

```
$filename = $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalName();
$file = $request->file('video')->storeAs('public/video', $filename);
```

I would like to get the absolute path to this.

---

**With storage_path():**

If I use the method `storage_path()` I can get the full path to the link of the file but not to the file on disk.

with this method I get:

```
/Users/MYUSER/laravel/storage/public/video/a.mp4
```

but should be:

```
/Users/MYUSER/laravel/storage/app/public/video/a.mp4
```

Comment: $file->getPathname()

Comment: hum... is the title go with the question ?

Comment: @JazZ whoops sorry, was from a draft...

Comment: Hehe, well done. Did the derek solution answered your question ?

Comment: @Derek `$file` is a string not an item, so it throws `Call to a member function getPathname() on string`

Comment: @JazZ unfortunately no

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774352/laravel-get-real-path-of-input-file

Comment: @JazZ This is what I've already done with the code above. I need the absolute path of the file already saved (with that code) and use it later with other libraries. I tried also `realpath($file)` but return false.

Comment: @JazZ could be a solution but what if I have to upload one heavy file, can you imagine the time to move these files around the disk? Or if more user upload multiples files at the same moment. I won't believe that there isn't a solution to have the absolute path of a file.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine. Removed my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964412/how-to-get-file-path-using-storage-facade-in-laravel-5/28989266#28989266

Comment: With this it works! thanks @JazZ

Comment: Gad to hear that ! = ) I flag this as a duplicated question.